# Nginx Location Block being ignored

Tags: post, nginx, location

I've struggling to understand what is going on with POST requests in this Nginx config.  Based on the debug messages I added in there, when POSTing a request here, the headers that get added are the X-debug-messages 0 and 4.  It seems like the location block is being completely ignored.  Any ideas?

```
daemon off;
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    server {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        listen 80 default_server;
        location / {
            proxy_pass              $scheme://<dest>$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <hostname>;

        add_header X-debug-message0 "In the hostname server block" always;
        location / {
            add_header X-debug-message1 "Checking for POST method" always;
            if ($request_method = POST) {
                add_header X-debug-message2 "Ready for proxy_pass" always;
                proxy_pass https://www.<hostname>$request_uri;
                break;
            }
            add_header X-debug-message3 "Skipped proxy_pass" always;
            break;
        }
        add_header X-debug-message4 "Going to redirect" always;
        return 301 https://www.<hostname>$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen                443;
        server_name           <hostname>;
        ssl                   on;
        ssl_certificate       /app/certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key   /app/certs/cert.key;
        return 301 https://www.<hostname>$request_uri;    
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `return 301` in server block. It effectively prevents nginx from checking anything else

Comment: Really?  I thought the `break` after the proxy_pass would keep that from being evaluated.  And why would those other headers not get added as well?  Those are before the 301.

Comment: Well I guess the proof is in the pudding.  I put the return directive inside the location block and it's now working as expected.  Feel free to make your answer and I'll √ it.

Comment: Nginx's config is NOT a program that "executes" top to bottom